# Powershell export ACL permissions to CSV

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am still on the learning curve with powershell, i currently have the following script:

```
$users = Get-Acl $Path | 
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty access |
            ft identityreference | 
                where { $_.identityreference -like "UK\"}
```

$Path is the location of a particular share on a server. I currently have a CSV file called "test" with about 100 share names on the same server (The first column heading named "ShareNames"), the second column is named "GroupName".

I need to update this script to search through the first column in the CSV file called "test.csv" and push out the appropriate group permission to that share in the second column. I have to also admit the last part of the script does not work :( i am having trouble filtering out a common group name we have as i do not want the whole list of groups for every share only group names that start with ("uk\gro...").

Thank you for any guidance / help

Answer (score 0):

I would choose `-match` over `-like` and skip the `Format-Table`.  The following would filter the ACEs on their property `IdentityReference` using the regex `^UK\\` -- I am assuming that 'UK\' is the domain portion of the group name within the ACEs:

```
$user = Get-Acl $path |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty access |
    Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -match '^UK\\' }
```

Then you can `ft` as desired:

```
$user | Format-Table
```

---

If you need to feed in a CSV of paths, you can pipe an `Import-Csv` into a `ForEach-Object` wrapped around the above example.

```
 Import-Csv test.csv |
   ForEach-Object {
     Write-Output "ACEs on $($_.ShareNames) matching 'UK\'"
     Get-Acl $_.ShareNames |
       Select-Object -ExpandProperty access |
         Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -match '^UK\\' }
   }
```

I'm still not clear on how you intend to populate the "GroupName" column in the output as there could be multiple entries for groups beginning with 'UK\'.

Comment: Thank you that did sort the first problem out filtering the group names. Now i need a way of reading 100 share name locations from a csv and exporting the results into the same csv file in the second column.

Comment: @Phil To clarify, you want to read the CSV, and for each line perform the above `Get-Acl`, then write back out the share and ACEs to a CSV?

Comment: I have a CSV with two columns, the first column has arround 100 shared folder locations, the second column is empty i would like to fill the second collumn with all the filterd security groups in the above script you just helped me complete. The above only takes a single path, i need to edit and allow it to read a csv with all the shares

Comment: Dropped an edit, you'll need to indicate what you mean by "fill the second collumn with all the filterd security groups" -- would that be a delimited list? Concated? etc...